# What is the difference between Declare and System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute?

Tags: vb.net, declare, compiler-services

I'm using VB.NET and obtain an icon from a System-DLL. Therefore, I use [`ExtractIconEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As mentioned in the remarks, I'm using [`DestroyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to free the resources again.

So far, I used the line

```vb
Private Declare Auto Function DestroyIcon Lib "user32.dll" (
  ByVal hIcon As IntPtr) As Boolean
```

to declare that method.

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.fromhandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) example for `Icon.FromHandle`, I see they use

```vb
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function DestroyIcon(
  ByVal hIcon As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
```

What is the difference?

I'm especially riddled by that `DllImportAttribute` doesn't seem to work with the same ease as `Declare`. I made the following test:

I use [`GetPrivateProfileString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to obtain a String from an ini file.

```vb
Private Declare Auto Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" (
  ByVal lpApplicationName As String, 
  ByVal lpKeyName As String, 
  ByVal lpDefault As String, 
  ByVal lpReturnedString As String, 
  ByVal nSize As Integer, 
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
```

works; it writes the entry in the `lpReturnedString` buffer and returns 41.

```vb
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetPrivateProfileString(
  ByVal lpApplicationName As String,
  ByVal lpKeyName As String,
  ByVal lpDefault As String,
  ByVal lpReturnedString As String,
  ByVal nSize As Integer,
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
End Function
```

leaves `lpReturnedString` untouched, but returns the correct string length of 41.

Comment: The Declare keyword is legacy from earlier VB versions.  Does the exact same thing for simple winapi functions like DestroyIcon, but the DllImport attribute has more capabilities.  Do note that your declaration for GetPrivateProfileString() is dangerously wrong, strings are immutable, the pinvoke.net website can get you a better one.

Comment: Why don't you just use [Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and let the framework do the work instead of messing around with all those APIs?

Comment: @Plutonix What is that comment supposed to say? There is no answer to rate or accept here.

Comment: @HansPassant I know Strings are immutable and actually I have no idea why the declare version works. For future reference, the declaration from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) can be found [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetPrivateProfileString). It uses a `StringBuilder`, which I initialize with a capacity of my buffer size. With that modification, `DllImportAttribute` works as well.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Because it is actually a resource DLL and not an image file. The DLL contains hundreds of icons, and all I know is that I want the one with the index XYZ.